# What could cause false change of sha1 checkmap?

Tags: java, git, sha1, checksum

I am boggled by the fact that the `sha1` sum started to change without change in the java classes.

I have reverted changes to the files, recompiled the project and I get a different checksum than the one that should be. The last change of the package was 1 year ago, and it started to give a different sum Today.

My question is:

What if anything, can be the cause of a `sha1` sum to start giving a different result ?

Like I said the files have been reverted to the state that they were 1 year ago and still different.

Comment: Maybe whitspaces? These are sometimes ignored by version control.

Comment: Which source control management system do you use?

Comment: well, I reverted it so it should be identical, no ? I'm using eclipse+git for version control

Comment: Git can modify line endings when getting text files to match the target OS

Answer (score 0):

If you use a different compiler or a different version of the compiler or even different settings to the compiler it could pretty well be, that a different `.class` file is generated checksumwise. It should behave the same though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out tests that use these files were the culprit.